# Update Magento 1.4.1.1. to first 1.4.2 but "No releases for package "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest" exist"

Tags: magento-upgrade

I'm using exactly the same method described in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/connect-magentocommerce-com-core-to-upgrade-from-1-4-1-1-to-1-6) but i get the following errors:

> No releases for package "magento-core/Mage_All_Latest" exist
>
> Cannot initialize
>   'channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Mage_All_Latest-stable',
>   invalid or missing package file
>
> Package
>   "channel://connect.magentocommerce.com/core/Mage_All_Latest-stable" is
>   not valid
>
> upgrade failed

I have googled and tried to find a solution but no success. Can anybody help me that which procedures i have to try next?

Thank you!